# How to use dark mode dock with light mode system

Tags: dock, themes

I am using Light appearence on mac OS Big Sur.

We can set specific applications light/dark mode with this terminal code.

For example

`defaults write com.google.Chrome NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool yes`

It makes Google Chrome light mode with dark system theme. Similarly to I typed

`defaults write com.apple.dock NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool no` to use dark dock and it didn't work. I have checked the `com.apple.dock` package is exist.

How can I use dark dock on mac OS light mode? Thanks.

Comment: I think the issue is that `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` can switch dark mode off per app, but I'm not sure it can switch it on.

Comment: Yes, that could be true :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have **Light Mode enabled** in **System Preferences**
2. Open **System Preferences** on your Mac
3. Tap **General**
4. **Under Appearance**, select **Light**
5. Open **Terminal** on your Mac
6. Enter **the following prompt** into the command line:

`defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes`

After you have entered the prompt above and hit Enter, you may be prompted to enter your password. Do so, and then hit Enter again. Here’s what you’ll need to do next:

1. **Tap the Apple logo in the top right** of the Menu Bar
2. At the bottom of the list, select **Log Out**
3. After you have logged out of the computer, go ahead and log back in
   **Open System Preferences**
4. Tap **General**
5. Under Appearance, **select Dark**

In the event that you are done experimenting with changing how macOS looks, you can revert it back. This makes it so that the entire Mac system is in Dark or Light mode when making the selection in System Preferences.

The System Preferences panel stays the same as it was when you had opted for Light Mode. But both the menu bar AND the dock are in dark mode!

`defaults write -g NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool No`

Source : https://appletoolbox.com/can-you-use-a-dark-menu-bar-and-dock-with-macos-catalina/